# How to check for new version of a dll as a pre-build process and throw a warning

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, assemblies, build-process, projects-and-solutions

I don't know if this is possible, and I don't necessarily need to do it in the way I've envisioned here so if you have a better idea on how to accomplish the same thing please do tell.

I have an enterprise project that contains several assemblies used by other projects. Every time I update the enterprise project, I have to copy over the appropriate assemblies into the SharedDependencies folder for whichever UI project uses them. As you can imagine, it gets frustrating during testing when we forget to copy them over. We can't automatically copy them as a post build event because if we make breaking changes then we don't want all projects using the assembly to automatically get the new version.

What I think would be ideal is if I could write a pre-build command that would check to see if there is a newer assembly available and throw a warning if there is. I'm not sure how I would go about doing that though?

Comment: This feature already exists, you get a loud message when the [AssemblyVersion] of a reference assembly has changed.  Getting programmers to pay attention to it and stopping them from setting the Specific Version property of the assembly reference to False is a discipline problem.  No automation can fix that.

Answer (score 2):

*Anything* is possible, but is it right?

Consider this...
The situation you described is exactly what [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/) & [Nuget Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore) was designed to handle. It may take a bit of effort to migrate these shared libraries to a package but it is absolutely worth it.

> I have an enterprise project that contains several assemblies used by
>   other projects.

Nuget can be a key facilitator for reliable distribution of shared libraries. It's prudent to use a ["no-commit" strategy](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) by ignoring the nuget package directory when used in conjunction with TFS or Git. This can reduce commit bloat and the introduction of human error. Once package restore is added to a project, packages can be automatically downloaded by VS at build-time. You can pull a commit and be reasonably assured that you will have the right libraries.

> As you can imagine, it gets frustrating during testing when we forget
>   to copy them over. We can't automatically copy them as a post build
>   event because if we make breaking changes then we don't want all
>   projects using the assembly to automatically get the new version.

Not all packages are meant for production. Nuget will allow you to use semantic versioning to [identify a package as in a "pre-release" state](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning#Prerelease_Versions). This will prevent developers from accidentally using a package that is not in a final state. In order the see the package, the developer with have to willingly filter the package list to display the available pre-release versions and then add it. This will allow you to reliably share the package for testing purposes while shielding it from production usage. Committing the project in this state however will lock the pre-release package into the build. So be weary.

If you can be reasonably assured that your team can adopt this strategy, it will pay off in the long run. One thing you should be aware of however is that after you have created packages for consumption, you don't need a web server to use them (although its a good idea). Even [a network share](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds#Creating_Local_Feeds) can suffice as a package source.

Comment: Thanks Nick, +1 for the answer although I'm not really in a position to implement this and even if I was I have a feeling that putting it in motion would take longer than it sounds like between learning how to do it and then actually doing it and making sure others are on board with what's going on.

Comment: NP, The only other option for you would be to get down and dirty with MSBuild (*shudder*) and start scanning assembly manifest data on your shared libraries to check versions and copy appropriately.

Comment: Actually here's a thought. Why not bind a copy task to a specific build config.. i.e. debug vs. release and choose the right one for the right situation.